# Load bootstrap slider after the text fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a full-width background image which appears first when the page loads. And after 5 seconds I have a text that fades in.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.fadetext').fadeIn("slow");
}, 5000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bigbackgroundimage">
  <div class="fadetext" style="display: none;">
    <img src="images/home/home-text.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

After 5 seconds of the fadeIn text, I want to load the bootstrap slider. How is this possible?

I tried using setTimeout function using 10 sec

```
 setTimeout(function(){
   $('.carousel').carousel({
     interval: 5000
   });      
 }, 10000)
```

This doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What have you tried so far with the slider and what happened? Do you have it loading immediately and just need to delay it?

Comment: I tried using another setTimeout function with 10 sec delay. Also I want those image to be slide with 5 sec interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit per your comments - start off the carousel hidden with `display:none` in your css, then in the callback function, show the carousel before you initialise it

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.fadetext').fadeIn("slow", function() {
    // this is run after the fadeIn has finished
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.carousel').show().carousel({
        interval: 5000
      });
    }, 5000) // can set this to 5 seconds 
  });
}, 5000)
```

```css
.carousel {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: But I can see the carousel already loaded in the browser. Isn't it possible to hide it first only show the carousel only after 5 sec of text fade?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `.done()`

```
$('.fadetext').fadeIn("slow").done(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.carousel').show().carousel({
            interval: 5000
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```